# Could life similar to life on earth exist and evolve in a large enough region of timespace?

Tags: biology, black-holes

Is it possible for a planetary system to form and support life similar to earth-life inside a region of 'timespace' (which is the space within a black-hole), assuming that there is enough space/time for a habitable orbit and for life to evolve into complex forms.

Comment: Does this https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10153/30492 answers your question?

Comment: No, as that question asks about a planet orbitin the singularity, rather than orbiting a star inside the black hole

Comment: As far as anyone knows, there aren't any stars or planets or anything else *inside* the black hole, any more than there are planets inside stars. All that's inside the black hole is... the black hole.

Comment: @IchthysKing: The difficulty with a habitable planet orbiting a star inside the black hole is the HABITABLE part. Not the STAR part.

Comment: @IchthysKing: On that note do you know if the space inside the event horizon (presumably this is what you mean by the space within a black-hole) is empty or full of matter? I know there is believed to be a singularity in the centre and a shell of matter around the event horizon. But that doesn't rule out the rest of it being full up too!

Comment: We simply do not know what happens after the event horizon, which makes your question impossible to answer.

Comment: Considering that some cosmologists think the universe IS a big black hole, I'd have to say the answer is probably yes :-)

Comment: But the black hole is filled with timespace, which is unlike spacetime surrounding us

Comment: Anything is possible if your physics textbook is thick enough.Sci-Fi is all about exploring thicker physics textbooks before they are written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Event horizon of a black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Event_horizon_of_a_black_hole)

> According to the fundamental gravitational collapse models [12], an event horizon forms before the singularity of black hole. If all the stars in the Milky Way would gradually aggregate towards the galactic center while keeping their proportionate distances from each other, they will all fall within their **joint** Schwarzschild radius long before they are forced to collide.
>
> ... In realistic stellar black holes, spaghettification occurs early: tidal forces tear materials apart well before the event horizon. However, in supermassive black holes, which are found in centers of galaxies, spaghettification occurs inside the event horizon. A human astronaut would survive the fall through an event horizon only in a black hole with a mass of approximately 10,000 solar masses or greater.

So, yes, it is possible to have solar systems inside the event horizon of super-hyper massive blackholes.
In respect with the evolution of life... it's hard to tell, for a galaxy-wide black hole to form, the density of stars should be quite high. Which means the radiation from unruly neighboring stars is way higher and the impact of a supernova is felt (due to the smaller distance) much stronger.

---

One interesting question would be if it is possible to have black holes inside (suppa-duppa massive) black holes.

Comment: But, what if the planet was in an isolated black hole, so that radiation and supernovae are less of an issue?